# Remove literals from input value before validation and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, maskedinput

I have a form with a required phone number field that looks like this with the maskedinput plugin

(999) 999-9999

I want the jquery validation to ignore the literals in order to validate this.  Also, i want the literals to be removed before the form is submitted.  But if there is a validation error i still want the maskedinput plugin activated so the format looks correct for the user still.

I figure i could edit the regex for the validation but then when the form is submitted the literals will still be on there.

Let me know i need to explain this better.

Any Ideas?  I'm pretty new to jquery and all so detailed solution would be great.

My javascript code is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "US Phone Number Required");


    $("#valform").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            $("#error-message").show().text("Please correct the required field(s)");
        } else {
            $("#error-message").hide();
        }
    },
    messages: {
        phone: {
            required: ""
        }
    },
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        },

        },
     });



    $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999",{placeholder:"  "});


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the other characters before submitting the form using js

This code will remove the forbidden character from the input as soon as its entered.

The input field has the class "numbers". This binds the "keyup" event to that input field and calls a function called "handleInputKeyUp"

```
 $(".numbers").bind("keyup", handleInputKeyUp);
```

The function:

```
function handleInputKeyUp(e){    

    var temp = e.currentTarget.value;
                temp = temp.replace(/[^\d-]/g, "");
                e.currentTarget.value = temp;
    }
```

This code removes all but digits and - from the input field.

Comment: You may want to escape the `+` character.

Comment: @DavidThomas Not if you want to input a phone number, it could be used

Comment: Yes, but without being escaped it's a regexp special character? Or am I missing something, it's still a little early...

Comment: Can you put exactly what needs to be added put in the head script and where?  sorry not good with javascript yet